# Javascript named function definition executed when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

I have no idea what is happening here. The code is:

```
  if( true ) { 

      console.log('In first function definition');

      function test(){
        console.log('Hello world');
      }

    } else {

      console.log('In the second function definition');

      function test(){
        console.log('Goodbye world');
      }

    }

  test();
```

I would expect this to log in the console:

```
'In the first function definition'
'Hello world'
```

But instead it logs:

```
'In the first function definition'
'Goodbye world'
```

How is the second named function being created when the code doesn't enter that branch?

Comment: why do you want to re-define same function name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember, everything in JavaScript is function-scoped; there is no block scope.

To that effect, you have two function declarations defined in the *same* scope (whatever the scope that if-else sits in), with the same name, in different blocks.  This produces inconsistent results between browsers.

You need to either give those functions different names, or use function expressions, with something like this:

```
var f;
if(true) { 
   console.log('In first function definition');

   f = function(){
     console.log('Hello world');
   };

} else {
  console.log('In the second function definition');

  f = function(){
    console.log('Goodbye world');
  };
}
f();
```

---

To your excellent question of

> But how is the function defined, if we don't enter that branch of the code? If that block is not executed, why is scope a consideration?

The simple answer is that function declarations are "hoisted", and **immediately** available *anywhere* in the scope, even before the declaration itself.

ie:

```
function foo(){
    f(); //perfectly valid

    function f(){
    }
}
```

The longer answer is that, prior to entering the scope, all variable declarations, and function declarations are stripped out, and placed onto the "activation object."  The activation object is then placed at the head of the "scope chain."  When you execute the function, any references to these variables and functions are simply resolved from there.

Comment: But how is the function defined, if we don't enter that branch of the code? If that block is not executed, why is scope a consideration?

Comment: But they're supposed to be function *expressions*, not function *definitions*. The JS engine is getting it wrong.

Comment: -1: it's not nondeterministic, it's perfectly deterministic - it's exactly as if the blocks get cut out of the code and moved to the top of the function, then the rest of the function runs. i'm pretty sure that's in the spec. desirable? no, but it's well-defined... the issue is with function declarations being wonky, not with the scope being wonky.

Comment: @Claudiu - two function declarations of the same name produce deterministic behavior?  Are you sure?  I thought I remembered reading otherwise

Comment: oh i see in your edit you just pointed that out, alrighty. still not nondeterministic though!

Comment: The "hoisted" part is the reason.

Comment: @AdamRackis: it's deterministic in that the same thing happens each time, without variation. it might be though that different engines treat it differently (read: not according to the spec), which is a different issue

Comment: +1 — function expressions are the key to consistent results. Some browsers allow conditional declarations (e.g. Firefox) but others don't (e.g. IE). Using expressions provides consistent results.

Comment: @Claudiu - so the spec has a properly defined behavior for multiple function declarations with the same name in the same scope?  If so I'll happily edit that part out.

Comment: @Claudiu—you're right. Different browsers treat conditional declarations differently so they should not be used. Firefox uses a variation allowed by ECMA-262 to produce what appears to be conditional declarations, IE (for example) does not.

Comment: Ahh hoisting. I suspected it was something to do with that. Very Interesting. I had never been bitten by it before surprisingly. Will need to have another look at how function definitions are treated in js. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Note that in strict mode functions cannot be nested in blocks.

Comment: @AdamRackis: *" so the spec has a properly defined behavior for multiple function declarations with the same name in the same scope?"* Yes: When there are multiple declarations in the same scope, the last one wins; [Section 10.5](http://bit.ly/11k8r7u) makes this clear. But the declarations above are **invalid** because they're in conditional blocks, which is not allowed. [Section 12](http://bit.ly/15zQ2H8) even specifically calls this out. Some engines tolerate them, but they are not consistent with each other (or even earlier versions of themselves).

Comment: @RobG: Right, but that treatment is Firefox-specific and invalid according to the specification. It's not consistent across engines, or even within versions of Firfox's SpiderMonkey engine, which at one stage rejected them, and at other stages rewrote them (effectively) as function expressions (your "function statement" treatment). So until/unless ESx defines a function statement, best not to rely on the behavior.

Comment: @Reinmar—not "cannot be", but [recommended against](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—yes, specific to Firefox among common web browsers (though the spec says "Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript", so perhaps there are others). And yes, certainly to be strongly recommended against when there is a robust, consistent alternative, though it's not quite the same.

Comment: @RobG: The only difference I see in Firefox's treatment of it is that if you use `var foo = function() { ... };`, the function is anonymous. `var foo = function foo() { ... }` would be exactly the same, but of course, [IE8 gets it wrong](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) (although in a way that's *usually* mostly harmless). But the main point is that relying on Firefox's non-standard behavior is a very bad idea because other popular engines (say, V8) don't do it. http://jsbin.com/eluruk/1 results in "1" on Firefox and "2" on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. - so those functions **DO** produce undefined behavior, but because they're defined in control blocks, not because they have the same name.  Thanks much!

Comment: @AdamRackis: Well, not undefined behavior - it's defined in the spec. Ah yes I like the way you phrased it - "inconsistent results between browsers". that's the best way to put it.

Answer (score 2):

Function definitions in javascript are independent of control structures, meaning that when you redefine the function the second time even though it's in a branch of a control structure that will never bit hit it still redefines the function. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: That's not how it works in practice. Firefox allows conditional function declarations.

Comment: @RobG: It is with some engines, such as Chrome's V8. Or indeed, anything strictly following the specification.

Answer (score 1):

[Some JavaScript engines treat the definition as always occurring regardless of the condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Conditionally_defining_a_function), and the second definition overwrites the first.

> Note: Some JavaScript engines, not including SpiderMonkey, incorrectly treat any function expression with a name as a function definition.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good to see more info on it with regard to it being vendor conditional.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930814/30433), you can get a way around it if you assign your function.

```
if( true ) { 
  console.log('In first function definition');
  test = function() { console.log('Hello world'); }
} else {
  console.log('In the second function definition');
  test = function(){ console.log('Goodbye world'); }
}
test();
```

This will print

> In the first function definition
>   Hello world

Comment: Thanks. I'm defining the functions conditionally like this now :)

Comment: @BIOS: FWIW, Ashwin's expressions are missing semicolons at the end. The horror that is "Automatic Semicolon Insertion" will add them if the code is formatted as above, but it's not something I recommend relying on.

Comment: Hey yeah i just meant i was creating functions by assigning anonymous functions to variables now, not using this code but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to ECMA-262, function declarations are processed before any code is executed. So declaring functions anywhere effectively moves ("hoists") them to the top of the execution context.

However, not everything that looks like a declaration **is** a declaration. In the following:

```
if (false) {
  function fred() {return true;}
}
```

Some browsers see a function declaration so:

```
alert(fred());
```

shows "true". Other browsers use an extension to ECMA-262 that allows it to be treated as a <strike>named function expression</strike> function statement (<strike>I'll try to find a reference to an excellent posting by Richard Cornford on comp.lang.javascript about that</strike> see below), so that:

```
alert(fred());
```

throws as an error that *fred* is undefined. Try it in Firefox and IE.

So the bottom line is if you want to conditionally create a function, use an unambiguous function expression. They're often used in conjunction with feature testing, e.g. to create a function to get the textContent or innerText of an element:

```
var getText = (function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');

  if (typeof div.textContent == 'string') { 
    div = null;
    return function(el) {return el.textContent;};

  } else if (typeof div.innerText == 'string') { 
    div = null;
    return function(el) {return el.innerText;};
  }
}());
```

#### Edit

Here's Richard Cornford's post in [FunctionExpression's and memory consumptions](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/6eb53953ca5ce6eb?hl=en). The important part:

> In fact it is a function statement; a syntax  extension that is
>   capable of allowing the conditional creation of a  function because
>   being a Statement it can be evaluative inside a  block.

But the whole post is worth reading.

Also note that function statements are [warned against in ES5 strict mode](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12) and may be introduced in some future version of ECMAScript.